# Add additional string parameter into DispatcherTimer EventHandler

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatchertimer

How can I add extra string parameter into Dispatchertimer Eventhandler ?.

I would like achieve something like this:

```
string ObjectName = "SomeObjectName";
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick(ObjectName));
```

And function:

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e, string ObjectName)
{
    [...]
}
```

How Can I achieve that?

Edit:

My intention is add some animation for moving object. I've got canvas with few objects. I can move this objects on canvas by mouse clicking, i would like to add animations for this movement.

Comment: What you posted compiles in .NET 4

Comment: @GaneshR. Unless `dispatcherTimer_Tick` was a function actually returning an `EventHandler` (which it isn't), that could never compile.

Comment: @Chris Yup. I had created the dispatcherTimer_Tick method using ReSharper which returned an EventHandler

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a *closure* for that:

```
... 
{    
    string objectName = "SomeObjectName";
    var dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

    dispatcherTimer.Tick += (sender, e) => { myTick(sender, e, objectName); };
}

private void myTick(object sender, EventArgs e, string objectName)
{
    [...]
}
```

---

Note, though, that the *variable* `objectName` is captured, rather than it's current value. That means if you do this:

```
... 
{    
    string objectName = "SomeObjectName";
    var dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

    dispatcherTimer.Tick += (sender, e) => { myTick(sender, e, objectName); };
    objectName = "SomeOtherObjectName";
}
```

myTick will be called with `SomeOtherObjectName`, which might be counter-intuitive at a first glance. The reason for this is that, under the hood, a separate object instance with an `objectName` field is created -- very similar to what [Chris' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28138145/87698) is doing explicitly.

Comment: @Chris: It's basically an implicit variant of what you are doing explicitly.

Comment: Yeah, just wish I had thought of that before my solution hehe.

Comment: imma just say, registering Lambda like that to this event has extreme limitations, for one, it can be registered multiple times and you cant unregistered it through -=, thus limiting you to an one time only use, just using an outer score field would be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this trick to pass along as much data as you'd like:

```
class Foo
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
    // ...

    public void OnTick( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        // logic here
    }
}

var f = new Foo() { PropertyA = "some stuff here",
                    PropertyB = "some more stuff here" };
dispatcherTimer.Tick += f.OnTick;
```

Obviously, if you only ever have one event handler for the same timer you could just as well store the required data in whatever class is using this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Tag` property of DispatcherTimer

```
string ObjectName = "SomeObjectName";
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
dispatcherTimer.Tag = ObjectName
```

Then

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var timer = sender as DispatcherTimer;
    
    var objectName = (string)timer.Tag;
       
}
```